# Write requests to log file in IIS

Tags: iis, logging

I have a cabinet which consists of several servers, handling quite a bit of traffic.
I need to construct a system to keep statistics - and I struggle to find out if it's possible or makes sense to make a null-request to a server? That is, calling something like `http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX?objectid=9563828&sreq=2854&nc=29291947829` and letting IIS do nothing with it, except adding the request in the log.

As mentioned, my servers handle a lot of traffic - and every bit of CPU-power and byte I can save, counts in the long run = save money.

At the moment, my plan is to make IIS return nothing on 404-errors, but I'm not sure if this is the best approach. And are all requests logged (having caching in mind)?

Theories or suggestions, please?

Comment: How will a null request help you track statistics?

Comment: Because a lot of the incoming traffic is going to be non-cacheable requests that aren't looking for a specific file from files that aren't nescessary located on our server, for instance a click on a button, adjusting sound etc. We could call a physical file, like a 1x1 gif with parameters, but we're talking about hundreds of millions of requests, so we need to keep the server load at a minimum, as well as keeping the log as tidy as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it is possible by adding

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

in the configuration file. The reason I didn't succeed, is that this command is apparently only supported from IIS 7.0 and later and I was testing it on a version 6.5